# Gathering javadocs from multimodule maven project

Tags: maven, javadoc, doclet, qdox

In a large maven multimodule context,

**how can I gather javadoc-comments programmatically for a specific set of classes (e.g. all classes implementing some interface) or modules ?**

I have tried a stupid [doclet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html) and looked at [QDox](http://qdox.codehaus.org), but neither seems to do the job well.

Actually I think this should be simple if done correctly.

**Specifically, I do not know how to do this in a maven-build: How can I depend on and use the src-jars?**

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible with QDox, as long as you have the sources. QDox-2.x can also read source-files from jars, which can be generated by the maven-source-plugin.